# Checking if Database Table exists

Tags: database, mysql

I read the wordpress codex and professional wordpress. It seems both use something like

```
if($wpdb->get_var("SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'") != $table_name) {
```

to determine if the table exists. Is there any reason why `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ( ... )` is not used? It will check and create the table in 1 query, won't it be better? Or am I missing something?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you use "IF NOT EXISTS" then the dbdelta script will not upgrade your database with delta's appeared after the initial creation of the database.

(assuming you want to re-use the same sql script)

at least... that is what i think

Answer (score 8):

Try this one:

```
global $wpdb;
$table_name = $wpdb->base_prefix.'custom_prices';
$query = $wpdb->prepare( 'SHOW TABLES LIKE %s', $wpdb->esc_like( $table_name ) );

if ( ! $wpdb->get_var( $query ) == $table_name ) {
    // go go
}
```

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?

Answer (score 5):

DISCLAIMER : I'm not a WordPress Guru, only a MySQL DBA

If you want to user a different query, try this

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema='dbname' AND table_name='tbname';
```

It will either return 0 (if table does not exist) or 1 (if table does exist)

Answer (score 5):

**TL;DR**

```
require_once ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php';
global $wpdb;
$tablename = 'myTable'; 
$main_sql_create = "CREATE TABLE $tablename";    
maybe_create_table( $wpdb->prefix . $tablename, $main_sql_create );
```

---

WordPress now provides the `maybe_create_table` function - see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_create_table/

Before calling this function you have to manually include the `upgrade.php` file, otherwise you will get a fatal error like follows:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function maybe_create_table()

Comment: Welcome to WordPress Development! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how or why this works, but I can do:

```
if (in_array('snippets', $wpdb->tables)) {
  // do something if wp_snippets exists
}
```

Comment: this only works for core tables as I find while testing

Comment: it worked for me for detecting Code Snippets plugin's table.

Answer (score 1):

I understand this is really old question, but maybe some one find it usefull.
Small calss that handle function on new DB, version of table and create if does not exists.

```
class ACCESS_TBDB {
 private $wpdb = null;
 private $accessTable = 'table_prefix'; // just name of your table prefix
 private $accessTableVer = '1.0.7'; // table version
 private $accessTableOptName = 'access_db_ver'; // name for option for db version

public function __construct()
{
    global $wpdb;
    //I does not like to call global $wpdb in every function in the class
    $this->wpdb = $wpdb;
    $tablename = $this->accessTable;
    //set our table prefix
    $this->wpdb->access_table = $this->wpdb->prefix . $tablename;

    // every time check if db need to be created or not
    $this->checkAccessDatabase();
}

private function createDBSQL(){
    // create db sql for table
    $charset = $this->wpdb->get_charset_collate();
    $sql = "
    CREATE TABLE {$this->wpdb->access_table} (
        id INT(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        name TINYTEXT,
        type VARCHAR(10),
        value SMALLINT DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        created_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (id)
    ) $charset;
    ";

    return $sql;
}

private function checkAccessDatabase(){

    $version = $this->accessTableVer;

    //handle DB versions
    $db_version = get_option( $this->accessTableOptName , '0.0.0');
    
    //Without we will face error on dbDelta and maybe_create_table
    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php');
    $dbCreateSql = $this->createDBSQL();
    
    // check if maybe DB need upgrade
    if (version_compare($version, $db_version, '>')) {
        
        // if it contain old dev/legacy versions
        if (version_compare($db_version, '1.0.0', '<')) {
            $this->wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS {$this->wpdb->access_table};");
        }

        dbDelta($dbCreateSql);

        update_option( $this->accessTableOptName , $version);

    }else{
        //https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/maybe_create_table/
        // just check DB if exist in case it was deleted because of reasons ... :)
        $recreate = maybe_create_table( $this->wpdb->access_table, $dbCreateSql );
        if(!$recreate){
            update_option( $this->accessTableOptName , $version);
        }
    }
    
 }
    ... other functions ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `get_var` function from `wpdb` class with an exception handling:

```
try {
    $wpdb->hide_errors();
    $wpdb->get_var( 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' . $wpdb->prefix . 'translator' );
    $wpdb->show_errors();
} catch (Exception $e) {
    error_log($e);
} finally {
    translator_create_db();
}
```

Reference: [SELECT a Variable](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb#SELECT_a_Variable)